# How long can be stringstream be?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, logging

Working with a big project in Visual Studio C++11.

To avoid latency I am trying to write the logs of a function(which can be huge and can go beyond 300000+ log lines since the function does some extensive calculations) into a std::stringstream and finally flushing it out to a file.

Is what I am trying to do a bad thing? Is there something I can do better? This is since I dont want to flush it out to a file everytime I want to write a log.

Tia!

Comment: why not write it straight out to the file? Are you multithreading? You could have 1 file per thread and inject timestamps so you can reconcile the logs.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, the constraint here is just the amount of space in your program's free store, which is effectively the amount of spare memory on your system (RAM, swap, whatever).

The stringstream's performance will degrade somewhat as its "contents" grow, because resizing the buffer requires copying its contents, and this is slower when there are more contents. You also potentially risk fragmenting your system's memory pool. It's hard to know from your description whether this is a factor (number of lines is not important here; number of *bytes* is).

Depending on how fast the log fills up, I would consider flushing to file more frequently, so that:

- this operation is relatively quick in itself, each time you do it, and
- you make use of the operating system's own very clever buffering algorithms, and
- you make use of the hard drive's own very clever buffering algorithms

as it doesn't make much sense to deliberately avoid all that mature technology.

Fundamentally, though, flushing in batches makes sense so your overall design sounds alright.

Comment: I'd tend to force a flush maybe every 4196 bytes or 5s (whichever is the smaller), but again that depends on how long your lines are as it may not be quite that simple

Comment: thanks! I found out after experimenting much that the files are usually less than 50,000 lines which makes the text file in the order of around 4 MB(+ or - 1 ). I am thinking of flushing out maybe every 500KB or even never. Would that hurt?

Comment: Also, I was wondering if the constraint is only the amount of program's free store, and I am fine with the performance of stringstream holding the entire contents(which could max to 5MB(but unlikely)) - performance aspect I found after multiple experiments and I am happy. Do you think I should flush at all except in the end? When I think the flush(and therfore file write) is my bottleneck? The main reason, I dont want to take time is because, the function does an operation for a specific amount of time and I dont want it to waste time on writing to a file.

Comment: @user9639921: You should measure it and find out.

Comment: thanks! Looks like it works fine with respect to performance. I am happy about it. Just wanted to make sure there is no other problem with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`std::stringstream` is a wrapper around `std::string` therefore the limit will be `std::string::max_size()` which is system/implementation dependent.

I'd experiment with flushing more often (not necessarily each time you want to write a single line) and only proceed to optimize if profiling reveals a significant toll.

Also keep in mind that the purpose of a log is usually to provide useful debugging info. If your program crashes and nothing was flushed, it gains you nothing. There should be a tradeoff between flushing after each line and never doing it.

Comment: On my system `max_size()` returns `9223372036854775807`. Don't think I'm ever going to get a buffer that large.

Comment: Wow! 9 exabytes of swap space? I'm impressed! max_size() may not be being absolutely honest with you, sorry...